# Can't Upload Image to the server file system Using Volley HashMap and Php

Tags: php, android, hashmap, android-volley

Am developing the android application for uploading image name to the database and image file to the database file system. First in android I changed the image to base64 format, post it to the database and encode it back to a file using Php encoding functions.

The code shown below are for android.

The problem is that the It only add the other things in the database table including the image name but i cannot post the image to the file system with the folder named images.

```
 {
             @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("desc","Desc");
                    params.put("image",System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
                    params.put("photo",imageToString(selectedImage));
                    params.put("title","title");
                    params.put("contact","0716098762");
                    params.put("price","376867");
                    params.put("category","w");

                    return params;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getmInstance(UploadImageActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
        private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte [] imgByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);

        }
```

PHP

```
$itemContact  = $_POST["contact"];
$itemPrice = $_POST["price"];
$itemDesc = $_POST["desc"];
$image_name    = $_POST["image"];
$category    = $_POST["category"];
$file_tmp = "images/$image_name.jpg";
$imsrc = base64_decode($_POST['photo']);

 file_put_contents($file_tmp, $imsrc);
$sql = "insert into sales_items values('','$itemTitle','$itemContact','$itemPrice','$itemDesc','$image_name','$category');";
```

Answer (score 2):

On developing the android studio that will share it contents in Facebook in failed to import the Facebook sdk from downloaded sdk . This is How i did to make sure that i could solve it.

From your Android Studio Editor Go to **File** ==> **Project Structure**. On the left side of the popup panel under Modules select **app**==> **Dependencies.**

project structure window 
[image]

From the right side of the panel select button **+** then select **Library dependence** .Scroll Down to Choose the Library for facebook sdk.

[select the right **+** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RtBH.png) 
[image]

Now if the facebook sdk library not in the list type **facebook** inside the search area and click the search button you can see the `"com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0`"
select the sdk from here
[image]
select it and press ok. Wait for Gradle to synchronize and You can use facebook sdk in your project.

Answer (score 0):

- 1-Download the sdk
- 2-go to new and add new module in address give the `fb sdk path`.
- 3-go to project structure and in dependency tab click on `+` icon and
  select module and choose `android.facebook`.